# Meteor Login token expiration

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I have a requirement to make login sessions expire after 24 hours and currently use the following:

```
Accounts.config({
    loginExpirationInDays: 1
});
```

It appears that a new login token is only created when the user logs out and logs back in, not when login `type: resume` (such as a page refresh).

If I wanted to make it so that login expiration occured after 24 hours of inactivity, would there be a recommended approach?  I think it would be pretty annoying for a user to suddenly be logged out while they are using the application.  Or maybe I still have this wrong?  Also, can someone confirm that previous login tokens are removed or invalidated after logging out?

Comment: Do you call this code on both the client and the server? I.E this issue? https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3656

Comment: Ah cool.  I only call this on the server.  I didn't realize they kept a Meteor.loginTokenExpires key in local storage.  It appears the same login token is kept on login type: resume, and so login expiration is not extended.  Thanks for the tip.  That answers part of my question.  I'll rephrase it with the new info.

Answer (score 1):

Detecting inactivity isn't specific to Meteor, so you might try looking into something like [jquery-idle-timeout](https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-idle-timeout) or [jquery-inactivity-timeout](https://github.com/adesigns/jquery-inactivity-timeout). Once you detect inactivity, you can just use `Meteor.logout()` to log the user out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Dean.  I ended up implementing something similar, however I found a helpful Meteor package that ended up tracking user activity on the client using jquery events on the client and then logging out users on the server after a duration of inactivity.  The package I used is [here](https://github.com/lindleycb/meteor-stale-session), but I had to modify it slightly to my needs.